# Netlogo: Can't set ALL patch colours according to ascii datset

Tags: ascii, netlogo, arcgis, raster, netcdf

As a Stack Overflow debutant, I apologise for any non- conformities!

I managed to import some - previously NetCDF format - ascii chlorophyll data into NetLogo. This is projected according to WGS 84, as is the associated shapefile describing some coastline - the model represents mostly a marine system. This all works well and the patches are easily set to adopt chlorophyll values. However, when it comes to colouring these patches according to the chlorophyll, only some adopt the correct colour; the rest simply remain black.

[Grey areas are land, and white clouds - other than that all patches have a chlorophyll value, but most are simply black.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGCiV.png)

I have tried changing setting all patches with a chl value of >= 0 as red, for example:

[All patches with chl >= 0 should be red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUYMu.png)

However, as can be seen, many remain black; this is despite having a chl value of >= 0. I have attached my code and any help with colouring the patches would be hugely appreciated.

```
extensions [gis]

globals [raster land]

patches-own [chl]

to setup
  clear-all
  load-chl
  load-land
  reset-ticks
end

to load-chl
  gis:load-coordinate-system ("E:/PhD/Data/Chl-a data/esriwkt.txt")
  set raster gis:load-dataset "E:/PhD/Data/Chl-a data/asciis/raster2.asc"
  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of raster
  gis:paint raster 0
  gis:apply-raster raster chl
  let min-chl gis:minimum-of raster
  let max-chl gis:maximum-of raster

  ask patches
    [ifelse (chl <= 0) or (chl >= 0)
      [set pcolor red]
      ;[set pcolor scale-color lime chl min-chl max-chl]
      [set pcolor white]
    ]
end

to load-land
  set land gis:load-dataset "E:/PhD/Data/GIS model spatial data/countries_shp/countries.shp"
  foreach gis:feature-list-of land
  [
    gis:set-drawing-color grey
    gis:draw ? 1.0
    gis:fill ? 2.0
  ]
end
```

Cheers,
Rob

Comment: Have you actually inspected some patches to check what the chl values look like? This way you can make sure the gis data is being applied correctly. In particular, you should click on patches of different colours and see what their chl value is.

Comment: Hi, I have done this, yes, which is why I'm so confused. The values seem to match up with the data, but I can't get the pcolor to set accordingly. Cheers

Comment: For some of the patches, only.

Comment: try `ifelse ((chl <= 0) or (chl >= 0))`. Since the `set pcolor` is inside the `ask patches`, I would expect that they would all be either red or white, since one of the two clauses must operate. If that doesn't work, please look at one of the black patches and let us know the value of chl.

Comment: Hi again Jen, unfortunately, that didn't work. Some random examples of chl values from black patches include: 0.184, 1.823, 2.488, 0.506 etc. These are all within the expected range. Additionally, it seems that turtles can roam about and report the chl value from their current location accurately, although it remains black... Very strange.

Comment: sorry, i've run out. I can't see any reason why it isn't getting to that piece of code for all patches, and the black ones have valid numbers. Only other thing is perhaps some of these apparent numbers are characters?

Comment: No problem, it is very puzzling. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Predictably, there was an obvious solution to my problem; the code

`GIS:paint 0`

overruled the

`set pcolor`

commands.